# Using otool -L shows only the library name and not the path it's linked to

Tags: cmake, dynamic-linking, conan, otool

Say I have Player.app which I linked to foo.dylib during building phase. When I do `otool -L Player.app/Contents/MacOS/Player`, this is what I get

```
    foo.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.255)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1000.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 164.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 23.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudioKit.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudioKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/Versions/A/CoreMIDI (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 69.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecording.framework/Versions/A/DiscRecording (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.11.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/WebKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 610.3.7)
    /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 2022.20.117)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 54.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1770.255.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1463.2.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Versions/A/CoreImage (compatibility version 1.0.1, current version 5.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1122.11.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Note the first line only says `foo.dylib`. Why does this happens and where is it supposed to be linked to?

The way I build my application is using CMake, and Conan to import foo.dylib (which I uploaded myself in a private Conan server).

Comment: How did you setup conan in CMakeLists.txt? I think you need to pass `KEEP_RPATHS` to conan setup in your cmake

Comment: I added these lines
`set(CONAN_SYSTEM_INCLUDES ON)`,
`include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake}` and 
`conan_basic_setup()`
And also added ${CONAN_LIBS} to the final `target_link_libraries()`

Comment: I tried adding `KEEP_RPATHS` to `conan_basic_setup()` but I'm still getting the same behavior.

Comment: Did you clean your build directory and rebuilt your project from scratch after adding `KEEP_RPATHS` option?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned before building again. `rm -rf *`, `conan install ..`, `cmake ..` then `make -j`

Comment: How was foo.dylib generated in the first place? Does it actually contain @rpath? The `KEEP_RPATHS` option keeps the rpath if it's already there, but doesn't add it if it's not. See the [CMake doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.20/prop_tgt/MACOSX_RPATH.html) on how to generate the @rpath in your library name when compiling.